# pyspark load csv file into dataframe using a schema

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and working on pyspark with Spark version 2.2.0 and Python version 2.7.12

I am trying to read 2 .csv files (has more than 1 header row) into 2 different dataframes with known schema and perform comparison operations.

I am unsure if there is any optimal/better method to create schema file (Includes Column name, datatype, nullability) and refer it in pyspark program to load into a dataframe.

I have coded as following for first file:

1. Create an yaml file to store file paths, and schema
2. Read the schema file and construct StructField(column name, datatype, nullanbility) dynamically in a loop. 
   Example:
   [StructField(column1,Integer,true), StructField(column2,string,true), StructField(column3,decimal(10,2),true), .... ]
3. Read the data file into RDD and remove 2 header rows (Will use subtract function)
4. Create dataframe using sqlContext.createDataFrame by passing RDD, schema structure.

I am able to do these steps for a sample data of first file.

Please suggest if there is any better way (I am yet to explore fromDDL option for StructType). After similar dataframe is created for second file, there are functional logic to be applied.

Thank you

Comment: just trying understand, each csv file of yours has '1' header . so, '2' csv file you have and want to "remove 2 header rows" with approach you said ?

Comment: csv files have 2 headers each

Comment: I am able to do those 4 steps & create dataframe. Keeping open to understand if there is any better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do this using yaml configuration file (store schema) and read from pyspark to dynamically construct the StructType.

It is working and meeting requirements. if there are any better methods, happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading in the file using pyspark spark.read.csv with stucttype for schema, options header=true and mode=DROPMALFORMED which would ignore any records that dont match schema.

Comment: Hi Ron D, It did not work keeping header=true. Instead what I did is to just enforce schema and not specify header. After that I filtered out 2 header records using dropna option. Keeping the question open for understanding which is a better method.